# Removing last array which is not uniform to previous arrays within a multidimensional array

Tags: php

When I print an array I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 300
            [2] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 600
            [2] => 900
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 800
            [1] => 700
            [2] => 300
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

The first three arrays are uniform but the last array contains a key which is empty. I want to remove that key which is not uniform when compared to the previous arrays and possibly contains null values. I’ve used `array_filter` like this:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    array_filter($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will serve your purpose:

```
$arr = array(
    array(200, 300, 300),
    array(500, 600, 900),
    array(800, 700, 300),
    array(null)
);

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if(!is_array($v) || array_keys($v) !== array(0, 1, 2))
    unset($arr[$k]);
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 300
            [2] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 600
            [2] => 900
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 800
            [1] => 700
            [2] => 300
        )

)
```